# how to implement RFECV and gridsearchCV in svm

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, gridsearchcv

I try to implement gridsearchcv and then rfecv on svm

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFECV
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report

param_grid = {'C': [0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000],
   'gamma': [1, 0.1, 0.01, 0.001, 0.0001],
   'kernel': ['linear','rbf','sigmoid']}

estimator = SVC(probability = True, coef0 = 1.0)

clf = GridSearchCV (estimator, param_grid, cv=10, verbose=True)

clf.fit(data_train, label_train)


selector = RFECV(estimator, step = 1, cv= 10)
selector.fit(data_train, label_train)

label_predicted = selector.predict(data_test)
print(classification_report(label_test, label_predicted, digits=4))
```

it shows an error
ValueError: when `importance_getter=='auto'`, the underlying estimator SVC should have `coef_` or `feature_importances_` attribute. Either pass a fitted estimator to feature selector or call fit before calling transform.
[here is output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3Mud.png)

Comment: Where exactly? Please post the full error trace (not here, edit & update your post) - see how to create a [mre] (if you indeed use `make_friedman1`, it would seem that you have not included the data generation code either).

Comment: @desertnaut I added the output Image snipped.